# Can diamond be grown on copper wires using chemical vapor deposition techniques?

Tags: chemical-engineering

I am asking this as a follow-up to another question I asked earlier. It is regarding how to make higher voltage transformers. Diamond is a good dielectric material and would be good for using as a dielectric barrier for wires wound into transformers. However, diamond is much too brittle to coat the wire and then wind, so my question is this:

Can diamond be grown on copper wires wound into a transformer shape using chemical vapor deposition techniques?

Comment: If it *could* be grown, would it adhere through a thermal expansion-contraction cycle??